# cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'

Tags: c#

When I try to run the following code it gives an error which is " Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int' ".

I have done a lot of searches, and sadly I wasn't able to find any help for such an error.

```
int sum1, cols, rows;

float h, twoEnds, x;

sum1 = (h - ((cols) * x) + twoEnds)) / (cols + 1);
```

Comment: `Keep in mind, I'm using C#.` then what is the reason for `c` and `c++` tags?

Comment: cast to `int`: `sum1 = (int) ((h - ... / (cols + 1))`

Comment: Yeah cause there is no implicit conversion present from float to int

Comment: Currently you're declaring `x` twice; that won't even compile.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I wrongly copied it right here, but in my code it's not declared twice. 

Anyway thank you guys it worked =)

Comment: "I have done a lot of searches, and sadly I wasn't able to find any help for such an error" - I find that hard to believe when copying your title into google returns 64k+ results

Comment: For such a calculation I never knew what's wrong. Therefore, I had to post it here, and hell yeah I got the help already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors puts it clear

> cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'

So you have a `float` result which can't be *converted implictly* to `sum1` which is of type `int`. Try converting/casting it *explicitly*:

```
 sum1 = (int) ((h - ((cols) * x) + twoEnds)) / (cols + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `h`, `twoEnds`, and `x` are all floats, the following equation will return a float:

```
sum1 = (h - ((cols) * x) + twoEnds)) / (cols + 1)
```

You can either change sum1 to be a float, or cast your equation to be an int like so:

```
sum1 = (int)((h - ((cols) * x) + twoEnds)) / (cols + 1));
```